# Should the time in "recorded at time" be somewhat same to "most recent transform" in rqt graph?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

.I have attached the image please have a look at it.
If you sense something wrong in my tf tree please do help me
Please follow the below link to view my tf tree

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hV4_JzC0dGHIFglA8hIPxH_nGZuOsWPe/view?usp=sharing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390607/should-the-time-in-%22recorded-at-time%22-be-somewhat-same-to-%22most-recent-transform%22-in-rqt-graph?/) by [sidharth.jeyabal](https://answers.ros.org/users/53096/sidharth.jeyabal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2021-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ues it should be same

Please follow the link for more detail

https://answers.ros.org/question/390609/message-removed-becuase-it-is-too-old-while-fixed-frame-is-set-to-map/

---

Originally posted by [sidharth.jeyabal](https://answers.ros.org/users/53096/sidharth.jeyabal/) with karma: 38 on 2021-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0